# Remove ".animated" class after play, and add it back in case element reloads. Plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, event-listener

I have a a CSS ".animated" class that is set by default on all the "drawer-wrapper" elements, like so:

```
<div class="drawer-wrapper animated">
foo
</div>
```

I made a function that removes this "animated" class as soon as the animation finishes, because the animated state was making problems later on with the z-index. Up to now, my function works.

But the second part of my function doesn't work: I want the "animated" class to be re-added to "drawer-wrapper" in case it is toggled to "display: none" by some other event. That way, when it is re-toggled back to "display: block", the animation can play again, and then be removed again, and so on. Here is my javascript:

```
function remove_and_add_animation() {
    var i;
    var a = document.querySelectorAll(".drawer-wrapper");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i].addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function(){
        this.classList.remove("animated")});
        a[i].addEventListener("animationend", function(){
        this.classList.remove("animated")});
        if (
        window.getComputedStyle(a[i]).display === "none"
        ) {
        a[i].classList.add("animated")
        }
    }
}
addEventListener("change", function() {remove_and_add_animation(); });
```

Thank you most dearly!!

Comment: Add a conditional to check if the element.style.display is equal to block, if it is, then run your function...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in that case, my function runs only when the element appears, but the "animated" class still won't be added back to the function after disappear + reappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second part of code is correct, however, the time you run the code is wrong.
Other part of your code is through EventListener.
When do you want to add class "animated" back?

Comment: I want to add "animated" back as  soon as the element appears again. Because in my website, at various points the element will be set to "display: none" and then "display: block" again by various other functions. That's why I thought adding it whenever the element disappears would also work, because whatever was added when it disappears will still remain until it appears again.

Comment: So finally I added a new event listener to listen to "click" as well as "change". Now it works! The problem was that the exeternal function that triggered my add_and_remove_element was not a "change" but a "click"